# Как задать ограничение по ширине для body

Tags: html, width, body

Проблема в том, что контент элемента **body**, выходит за его края во какой-то причине, вследствие чего весь контент распределяется по экрану неравномерно(вылазит вправо за границы) и появляется нижняя полоса прокрутки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно это исправить, желательно через **css**?

Comment: Устранять последствия вместо причины - так себе решение. Всё равно ведь потом явно вылезет этот косяк. На мобиле или при изменении контента.

Comment: Вот я и хочу узнать в чём косяк, чтобы исправить.

Comment: По картинке вам никто не поможет, тут не битва экстрасенсов. Попробуйте поочерёдно удалять элементы и смотрите когда пропадает горизонтальная прокрутка.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Как-то так попробуй

Comment: Такой вариант не работает. Все стили изначально обнулены. Если и использовать overflow, то overflow-x, чтобы убрать нижнюю полосу прокрутки, но в таком случае контент страницы съезжает вправо.

Comment: zhurof  правильно описал, не понятно что именно разваливает вам контент. Тут или поочередно убирать элементы (можна даже в девтулзах это сделать) или смотреть стили. Где-то у вас элемент с четко зафиксированными размерами... например width для картинки задали, а в стилях не сделали её резиновой... вообщем тут только гадать ели не показан код страницы